# How to Store a ZipFile Inside a ZipFile using the zipfile library in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to store a ZipFile inside a ZipFile, while i use the .write method to write the ZipFile object i end up getting an error "expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not ZipFile"

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> import zipfile
>>> child_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(StringIO(), 'w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
>>> parent_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfile.ZipFile, 'w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
>>> parent_zip.write("test.zip",child_zip)
```

Answer (score 0):

First:

The `ZipFile.write` method expects a filename as its first argument, and it will then open and read data from that file, writing it to the archive. You need to use the `writestr` method to write raw data into `parent_zip`.

Second:

You're creating `parent_zip` like this:

```
parent_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfile.ZipFile, 'w',
                             compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
```

But the first argument to `zipfile.ZipFile` is supposed to be "the path to the file, or a file-like object". You're passing a class, which doesn't make any sense. If you want to create an in-memory zipfile, you can pass in another `StringIO` instance, or you can provide a filename.

Third:

You're not going to be able to write the `child_zip` object itself to the file; you need to provide some sort of byte stream. In other words, you need to provide the bytes that comprise the `child_zip` archive.

Putting all this together:

```
>>> import io
>>> import zipfile
>>> child_zip_data = io.BytesIO()
>>> child_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(child_zip_data, 'w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
>>> child_zip.close()
>>> parent_zip = zipfile.ZipFile("parent.zip", 'w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
>>> parent_zip.writestr("test.zip", child_zip_data.getvalue())
>>> parent_zip.close()
```

This creates a new archive named `parent.zip` with a single archive member, a file named `test.zip`:

```
$ unzip -l parent.zip
Archive:  parent.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
       22  05-29-2020 11:45   test.zip
---------                     -------
       22                     1 file
```

And if we extract `test.zip`, we see that it's an empty zipfile:

```
$ unzip parent.zip
Archive:  parent.zip
  inflating: test.zip
$ unzip -l test.zip
Archive:  test.zip
warning [test.zip]:  zipfile is empty
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for response.
But,what if I am storing e.g. .txt or .csv(with different names) files inside the child_zip(zip folder) and inturn storing the child_zip inside parent_zip(outside zip folder). isn't that possible?

Comment: You have explained the latter, but i need along with the former one.

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I don't understand what you're asking. If you'd like to clarify your question (by editing the question) to show exactly what you want to do, I would be happy to update this answer.